# Why is gradient symmetric at optimal point for convex functions on the positive semidefinite cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

For a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, if $X^{*} = \underset{ X\succeq 0 }{ \operatorname{arg min}}f(X)$, then we have $$\nabla f(X^{*})\succeq 0, \qquad X^{*} \succeq  0, \qquad \left\langle \nabla f(X^{*}),X^{*} \right\rangle = 0$$ How can we show $\nabla f(X^{*})$ is symmetric?

---

I have proved everything else (see below). However, I'm running out of techniques to show that $\nabla f(X^{*})$ is symmetric, I have tried to use orthogonal component of skew symmetric matrix, and some other techniques. My intuition is that this is quite easy, and can be proven by contradiction by finding a direction to decrease in the positive semidefinite range. However, I have not come up with anything solid.

---

**Proof:** For $\nabla f(X^{*}) \succeq 0$, suppose not, $\exists u$ s.t. $u^{T} \nabla f(X^{*})u = u^{T}\otimes u^{T}vec(\nabla f(X^{*})) < 0$. $u^{T}\otimes u^{T} = uu^{T}$ which is a positive semidefinite matrix. Therefore, $\exists t > 0$ s.t. $f(X^{*}+tuu^{T}) < f(X^{*})$, which contradicts that $X^{*}$ is the global minimum.
Next we show $\langle \nabla f(X^{*}),X^{*} \rangle = 0$. Suppose not, if $\langle \nabla f(X^{*}),X^{*} \rangle < 0$, $\exists t> 0$, s.t. $f(X^{*}+tX^{*}) < f(X^{*})$. Similarly, if $\langle \nabla f(X^{*}),X^{*} \rangle > 0$, $\langle \nabla f(X^{*}),X^{*} \rangle < 0$, since we know for $0 < t < 1$, $tX^{*} \succeq  0$, we know $\exists 0<t<1$ s.t. $f(X^{*}-tX^{*})) < f(X^{*})$. Both cases contradict that $X^{*}$ is the global minimum.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the gradient needs to be symmetric for general $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat It is mentioned in all the papers I read and also from my professor that the gradient is positive semidefinite. It is also impossible to be a weird positive semidefinite matrix, as the gradient being symmetric is explicitly used in proofs. If it doesn't have to be symmetric, I would really appreciate if you can give an example

Comment: Also maybe assume slaters condition i.e. $\exists X \succ 0$ s.t. $f(X) < +\infty$, but this is a highly mild condition. My professor mentions this, but I guess unless f takes values on the extended reals, this is automatically true.

Comment: I added a simple example. If you restrict the domain to be the collection of symmetric matrices then the assertion is vacuously true, but there is no a priori reason for the gradient to be symmetric.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for the answer. I have given you an upvote. Maybe that's the prior restriction. But in that case, taking the gradient felt really weird. Is it basically just taking the gradient with respect to the upper triangular entries, and filling out the lower triangular with the same number so that it becomes a square matrix?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The gradient for a functional on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ does not have to be symmetric just because it is evaluated at some symmetric point. There may be some other context to your question that is missing.

Comment: Note that when you take the (Frobenius) inner product of the gradient, say $G$ with some symmetric point $H$, the you have $\langle G, H \rangle = \langle G^T, H \rangle$ and hence $\langle G, H \rangle = \langle {1 \over 2}(G+G^T), H \rangle$. So, if your world of discourse is symmetric matrices, then  ${1 \over 2}(G+G^T)$ is a representation of the gradient. However, you have the domain as $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ in the question.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. Thank you. I think the domain is probably the symmetric matrices. I'll have to double-check then.

Comment: Good luck! ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $f(X) = {1 \over 2} \| X-A\|_F^2$. Then $\nabla f(X) = X-A$.

A straightforward computation shows that $\min_{X \ge 0 } f(X) $ is attained at $X^*= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & {1 \over 2} \\ {1 \over 2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and we see that
$\nabla f(X^*) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -{1 \over 2} \\ {1 \over 2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.